# HTML page refresh

Tags: html

I have the following html script.  Its set to refresh every 900 seconds (15 minutes).  I'm hosting this website from my laptop at home using IIS and port forwarding.  If I want it to refresh it every 15 minutes, do I need to have the website open?  Would it refresh even if its not open?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="900">
</head>
<frameset rows="5%,*" noresize frameborder=0>
<frame src="header.html">
<frame src="main.html" name="big-frame">
</frameset>

</html>
```

Comment: If the website isn't open, there is nothing to refresh. Refresh in this context only means, "reload the already open site in a client's browser".

Comment: I don't think so. It's hard to understand what it means to refresh when it's not open.

Comment: Don't use framesets: "Deprecated
This feature is no longer recommended. Though some browsers might still support it, it may have already been removed from the relevant web standards, may be in the process of being dropped, or may only be kept for compatibility purposes. Avoid using it, and update existing code if possible; see the compatibility table at the bottom of this page to guide your decision. Be aware that this feature may cease to work at any time."

Comment: This is like the HTML version of "if a tree falls in the forest, and there's nobody there to hear it, does it make a sound?"

Answer (score 0):

Opening the site automatically refreshes it so... but your code still works. What I don't understand is if you actually tested your code, you would've known if it worked or not. Next time, test your code before asking.

Answer (score -1):

yeah it's right

`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="900">`

will refresh on 900 seconds or 15 minutes if browser is open but not visiting the page it will also refresh

Answer (score -2):

To refresh it you need to keep the site opened in browser. Cheers )

Comment: this should be a comment

Comment: It is not the answer?

Comment: Sorry, so who's right?  It says "visiting the page it will also refresh", but then below it says "To refresh it you need to keep the site opened in browser. Cheers )"